# Ubuntu 18.10 frequently crashing

Tags: drivers, nvidia, games, 18.10

My Ubuntu 18.10 (also happens on 18.04) PC is always crashing since I have an NVidia GPU. When I play CSGO it crashes after 2 to 4 minutes playing. Also when I am just using Firefox or something else it crashes after 1 to 2 hours. I switched to Linux to get fewer crashes, not more. My system specs are:

- GTX-1050ti - Nvidia-driver-396
- i5 7600k
- 16gb DDR4 RAM

I already tried doing a clean install and I tried different drivers but the issue still exists. I used this PC without the 1050ti for some time (only with the iGPU) and I never had crashea.

I would really appreciate some help because I just want to use this PC without these annoying crashes.

This is my apport.log:

```
ERROR: apport (pid 2335) Sat Oct 20 10:49:49 2018: called for pid 2321, signal 11, core limit 0, dump mode 1
ERROR: apport (pid 2335) Sat Oct 20 10:49:49 2018: script: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade, interpreted by /usr/bin/python3.6 (command line "/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade --download-only")
ERROR: apport (pid 2335) Sat Oct 20 10:49:49 2018: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
ERROR: apport (pid 2335) Sat Oct 20 10:49:55 2018: wrote report /var/crash/_usr_bin_unattended-upgrade.0.crash
ERROR: apport (pid 2830) Sat Oct 20 10:49:55 2018: called for pid 2821, signal 11, core limit 0, dump mode 1
ERROR: apport (pid 2830) Sat Oct 20 10:49:55 2018: script: /usr/share/apport/whoopsie-upload-all, interpreted by /usr/bin/python3.6 (command line "/usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/apport/whoopsie-upload-all")
ERROR: apport (pid 2830) Sat Oct 20 10:49:55 2018: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
ERROR: apport (pid 2830) Sat Oct 20 10:49:56 2018: wrote report /var/crash/_usr_share_apport_whoopsie-upload-all.0.crash
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution for my problem!

If anyone experiences the same issue, just try to add `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` to your kernel boot options. To do this permanently, edit /etc/default/grub:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

go to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and add `intel_idle.max_cstate=1`.

When you are finished update grub `sudo update-grub`
and reboot!

Answer (score 1):

Before you start uninstalling/reinstalling software, it wouldn't hurt to buy a can of compressed air at a computer store, and spray the dust out of the graphics card's heat sink. Hold a fan blade in place with your fingers to keep it from turning fast, so you don't damage the fan's bearings when you spray it with compressed air.

1. Open the terminal and type:

   ```
   apt-cache depends nvidia-driver-396 # if nvidia-driver-396 doesn't work try nvidia-driver-390
   ```

   The results of the above command list the dependencies installed by nvidia-driver-396. Look for dependencies installed by nvidia-driver-396, that is packages that have both *nvidia* and *396* in their package names. Check if they are installed or not using `apt policy <package-names>`. Uninistall nvidia-driver-396 and its installed dependencies with `sudo apt remove <package-names>`.
2. Reboot.

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```
3. Install nvidia-driver-410.

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install nvidia-driver-410 nvidia-settings  
   sudo reboot
   ```

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely a driver issue or you have dust built up on your heat sink trapping the heat from escaping

Comment: Unfortunately that did not fix my problem :(